# Functional programming: term for filtering then mapping?

Tags: dictionary, filter, functional-programming

Sometimes I find myself wanting to filter a collection, then map the results.

In JavaScript, for example:

```
var completedStepIds = steps.filter(function(step) {
    return step.isComplete;
}).map(function(step) {
    return step.id;
});
```

Or in C#/LINQ:

```
var completedStepIds = 
    from step in steps
    where step.IsComplete
    select step.Id
;
```

In there a term in functional parlance for this filter-then-map combination?

Comment: don't know if it's official but "apply-if" comes to mind

Comment: There's no need to coin a new term, because function composition is basically used for this in general (i.e. (map f.filter p) in Haskell) In particular, as @tokland nicely pointed out, the frequently occuring combination of filter and map is most often written as list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want list-comprehensions:

```
[f(x) | x <- list, g(x)] # Haskell
[f(x) for x in iterable if g(x)] # Python
```

Well, jQuery's `map` works this way, which is a list-comprehension in disguise:

```
> $.map([1,2,3], function(x) { return x != 2 ? 2 * x: null })
[2, 6]
```

On the other hand Prototype does not filter at all (which is the orthodox thing to do, a map should not reduce):

```
> [1,2,3].map(function(x) { return x != 2 ? 2 * x: null })
[2, null, 6]
```

I don't know which library are you using, but you can always write your own abstraction which clears null/undefined from the mapping:

```
steps.map_and_filter(function(step) {
    return step.isComplete ? step.id : null;
})
```